# Bootstrap IE7 grid padding adds to bounding box

Tags: css, grid, twitter-bootstrap-3

I have a standard 12 column bootstrap grid, with 4 columns (col-md-3) inside.

In IE7 the fourth column skips to the next line.

The problem is: each column is 25% wide, and has a padding of 10px. When calculated, the column's width = 25% of its parent + the padding.

So the padding is added outside instead of inside. Is there a way to fix this ?

Answer (score 0):

Bootstrap i using the css attribute

```
box-sizing
```

And as you can see [here](http://caniuse.com/css3-boxsizing) IE7 is not supporting this attribute.

There seems to be a fallback with JavaScrip [here](http://www.snackoclock.net/2012/08/simple-box-sizing-border-box-fallback-for-ie/), but I didn't test or use it, so I cant tell you how good it is.

Comment: This is a crazy solution. It would calculate widths for every element with a col-* class. It also breaks more than it fixes

Comment: I think I am going to rewrite the grid a little with IE7 fallback

Answer (score 0):

Bootstrap 3 doesn't support IE7 due to the use of the CSS attribute *'box-sizing'*, however there is a workaround that's helped for me.

Check out his GitHub project (in beta) that provides IE7 support.

https://github.com/coliff/bootstrap-ie7

Happy coding :)